# How to get single histogram plot for all groups in different colours?

Tags: python, visualization

I am using the below script to get the histogram plot for all values together. However, I want a single plot but different colours for different groups (A, B, C)

`data file`

```
Group_name  code-1    code-2    Expression
GroupA  6  6  1.21
GroupA  6  8  0.611
GroupA  6  1  0.448
GroupA  6  3  0.3587
GroupB  8  6  0.611
GroupB  8  8  2.11
GroupB  8  1  0.60113
GroupB  8  3  0.534858
GroupC  1  6  0.448
GroupC  1  8  0.60113
GroupC  1  1  2.2
GroupC  1  3  0.622206
```

`Script`

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,8)

g1 = sns.histplot(df.Expression)
g1.set(
    xlim=(-2,2),
    title="Expression"
)
g1.axvline(0.0, c='black', linestyle="--")
g1.axvline(df.Expression.median(), c='red', linestyle="--")

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `g1 = sns.histplot(df.Expression)`
to `g1 = sns.histplot(data=df, x="Expression", hue="Group_name")`

Here's the full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12,8)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Group_name": ["GroupA", "GroupA", "GroupA", "GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupB", "GroupC", "GroupC", "GroupC", "GroupC"],
    "code-1": [6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "code-2": [6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 3],
    "Expression": [1.21, 0.611, 0.448, 0.3587, 0.611, 2.11, 0.60113, 0.534858, 0.448, 0.60113, 2.2, 0.622206]
})
 
g1 = sns.histplot(data=df, x="Expression", hue="Group_name")
g1.set(
    xlim=(-2,2),
    title="Expression"
)
g1.axvline(0.0, c='black', linestyle="--")
g1.axvline(df.Expression.median(), c='red', linestyle="--")

g1.figure.savefig("hist.png")
```

'''[image: New output]

Comment: Thanks, very impressive Seaborn coding